# Switch page in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I open Chrome DevTools and then open a new tab (page), DevTools doesn't switch to that tab.

Is there a way to make DevTools use the new tab or do I need to open a new DevTools window for that specific tab?

I opened a new tab, looked for changes in DevTools. DevTools remained on the initially opened tab.

Comment: Each tab has its own devtools.